# backup local sql server db tables for use on hosted db server using visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and created database tables with relationships. Is there an easy way to save/view the sql and then run a new query on my hosted sql server db to create each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In Visual Studio you can right click on any database, hosted or local and use the publishing wizard. I followed the steps at this link as the wizard is not very user friendly. http://products.secureserver.net/products/hosting/PublishingWithDPW.htm

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 can do a lot of stuff around databases - but at some point, you just have to switch to SQL Server Management Studio, and this is one of those cases.

In SSMS, you can easily generate T-SQL scripts to create your database objects - tables, procedures, whatever. I don't know of any way to do this inside VS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually VS can make a full synchronization of a database against a known schema - very nice for source control. You need a high version, though - I think Ultimate. Check the different database style projects you have available.